# Angular ng-model send data as array to rails-api

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

When adding the `ng-model` directive to an HTML element, I usually do so with it attached to an object.  However, before sending the HTTP request, a portion of the data should be an array of objects.

In my rails-api I have a `User` model and an `Address` model.  The user has many addresses and the address belongs to a user.

The goal is to just take in the parameter via strong params and save each of the addresses (received as JSON, array of objs) and have them each be related to the user.

Currently, i'm numbering them and doing some extra manipulation prior to shipping the data off to the API.  Ex:

`<input type="text" ng-model="form.address1">`

And then for the second, `ng-model="form.address2"`.

How can I setup an array of objects using the `ng-model` attribute and add objects onto the array in my HTML?

Comment: Before you send it, take all the ng-models you need and shove them in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to array too:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form.address[0]"> Address 1
<input type="text" ng-model="form.address[1]"> Address 2
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/owpAqLLlgOjBKfqHSZ4U?p=preview